# How to properly do string concatenation in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am testing a mailer in Rspec and have run into a quirk with string concatenation. When I do it as follows:

```
it 'renders the subject' do
  expect(mail.subject).to eq('#{order.firstname} <#{order.email}> has made an order.')
end
```

I get the following message:

```
OrderMailer instructions renders the subject
 Failure/Error: expect(mail.subject).to eq('#{order.firstname} <#{order.email}> has made an order.')

   expected: "\#{order.firstname} <\#{order.email}> has made an order."
        got: "Joe <joe@mctester.com> has made an order."

   (compared using ==)
```

However when I do the following it passes:

```
it 'renders the subject' do
  expect(mail.subject).to eq(order.firstname + " <" + order.email + "> has made an order.")
end
```

What is the correct way to concatenate in rspec? I find the first way far easier on the eye and quicker to work with.

Comment: Unfair to downvote this question.  Yes, its a ruby noob mistake, but it was not a bad question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String interpolation only works with double quotes in ruby:

```
it 'renders the subject' do
  expect(mail.subject).to eq("#{order.firstname} <#{order.email}> has made an order.")
end
```

That should work.

Comment: Of course. I always been using double quotes in ruby almost exclusively so I never ran into this.